# Spring dependance error in my pom file

Tags: java, spring, dependencies

I'm having some errors attempting to run some dbunit tests on a simple spring project.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but interface was expected
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:86)
```

This is my error. I know it has something to do with the dependencies and i have been fiddling with them for awhile(upgrading and such). Here is my pom.xml for clarity.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>TheHitProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDBC etc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.R</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--DB unit  -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` to help resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring-test-dbunit` v. 1.1.0 requires Spring 4.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/1.1.0

You're not using Spring 4.

Comment: Thank you Dave, this was my problem of course. Appreciate the help

Comment: To finish the question the error is now java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load dataset from "classpath:songwriterData.xml" using class com.github.springtestdbunit.dataset.FlatXmlDataSetLoader Is this related to my dependancy change??

Comment: @StephenMcKenna Don't know; that's a separate question. Is it at the root level in src/test/resources?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Rookie mistake. If i was eligible to give you more than a green thumbs up I would. Thank you very much Dave. I would have been fiddling with updates for another hour quite clueless.